# Error in UseMethod("html_table") : no applicable method for 'html_table' applied to an object of class "xml_missing"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape just the schedule table off of https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/bethune-cookman/2020-schedule.html and I've seen other questions that addressed this same topic but when I follow that code (below) it still gives me the error that is in the title. Is there something I'm missing?

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/bethune-cookman/2020-schedule.html'
schedule <- url %>%
             read_html %>%
             html_nodes(xpath = '//comment()') %>%
             html_text() %>%
             paste(collapse='') %>%
             read_html() %>%
             html_node('table#schedule') %>%
             html_table()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. [To ask a good question,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it would help to know what you tried. Did you remove the last step of the pipe and examine the output? You say that other questions on SO address the topic, maybe link them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table is not in comments. Try -

```
library(rvest)
url <- 'https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/schools/bethune-cookman/2020-schedule.html'
schedule <- url %>% read_html %>%  html_node('table#schedule') %>% html_table() 
schedule

# A tibble: 30 x 15
#       G Date   Time  Type  ``    Opponent Conf  ``       Tm   Opp OT        W     L
#   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <int> <int>
# 1     1 Wed, … 7:00p REG   ""    Johnson… ""    W       110    68 ""        1     0
# 2     2 Sat, … 8:00p REG   "@"   Texas T… "Big… L        44    79 ""        1     1
# 3     3 Mon, … 8:30p REG   "@"   Omaha    "Sum… L        61    90 ""        1     2
# 4     4 Fri, … 7:00p REG   ""    Trinity… ""    W       100    42 ""        2     2
# 5     5 Fri, … 1:00p REG   "@"   Incarna… "Sou… W        83    58 ""        3     2
# 6     6 Sat, … 1:00p REG   "N"   Eastern… "OVC" W        66    63 ""        4     2
# 7     7 Sun, … 1:00p REG   "N"   St. Fra… ""    W        74    70 ""        5     2
# 8     8 Sun, … 6:00p REG   "@"   Georgia… "ACC" L        65    68 ""        5     3
# 9     9 Tue, … 7:00p REG   "@"   Stetson  "A-S… L        67    72 ""        5     4
#10    10 Sat, … 6:00p REG   "@"   Jackson… "A-S… L        60    82 ""        5     5
# … with 20 more rows, and 2 more variables: Streak <chr>, Arena <chr>
```